# Smart pointer mark II - my answer to C++ 11 shared_ptr

Tags: c++, memory-management, pointers

I am writing this smart pointer as a learning exercise.  Any feedback would be most appreciated.

Any flaws? Have I missed any test cases?

smart_pointer.hpp:

```
#ifndef SMARTPOINTER_HPP_
#define SMARTPOINTER_HPP_

#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
class sp {
public:
   sp(T* ptr) : ptr_(ptr), ref_cnt_(new unsigned(1)) {
      std::cout << "sp ctor. Address: " << ptr_ << ", ref_cnt_: " << *ref_cnt_ << '\n';
   }

   T& operator*() { return *ptr_; }
   const T& operator*() const { return *ptr_; }

   T* operator->() { return ptr_; }
   const T* operator->() const { return ptr_; }

   // access to raw ptr
   T* get() { return ptr_; }

   sp(const sp<T>& rhs) : ptr_(rhs.ptr_), ref_cnt_(rhs.ref_cnt_) {
      addref();
      std::cout << "sp copy ctor: " << ptr_ << ", ref_cnt_: " << *ref_cnt_ << '\n';
   }

   sp& operator=(const sp& rhs) {
      if(this != &rhs) {
         try_delete();
         ptr_ = rhs.ptr_;
         ref_cnt_ = rhs.ref_cnt_;
         addref();
         std::cout << "sp assignment: " << ptr_ << ", ref_cnt_: " << *ref_cnt_ << '\n';
      }
      return *this;
   }

   ~sp() { 
        std::cout << "~sp. Address: " << ptr_ << ", ref count before remove_ref: " << *ref_cnt_ << '\n';
        try_delete();  
   }

private:
   unsigned addref() {
      return ++*ref_cnt_;
   }
   unsigned remove_ref() {
      return --*ref_cnt_;
   }

   void try_delete() {
      if(remove_ref() == 0) {
         std::cout << "try_delete(): finally deleting ptr_ at address: " << ptr_ << ", ref count: " << *ref_cnt_ << '\n'; 
         delete ref_cnt_;
         delete ptr_;
      }
   }

   T* ptr_;                    // raw ptr
   unsigned* ref_cnt_;  // shared ownership
};

#endif //SMARTPOINTER_HPP_
```

Code to exercise:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include "smart_pointer.hpp"

// useless class just used to test with object more complex than int
class tester {
public:
   tester(const int id, const char* name) : id_(id), name_(name) {}

   const char* const get_name() const { return name_; }
   const int get_id() const { return id_; }

private:
   const int id_;
   const char* const name_;
};


// global vector to hold smart pointer
std::vector< sp<int> > gvs;


int main() {

   {
      std::cout << "Test with ints\n";
      sp<int> myptr1 = new int(3);  
      *myptr1 = 4;
      std::cout << "number: " << *myptr1 << '\n';

      {
         // test usage in collection
         std::vector< sp<int> > vs;
         vs.push_back(myptr1);
      }

      // global collection
      gvs.push_back(myptr1);


      // copying
      sp<int> myp2(myptr1);
      sp<int> myp3(myptr1);
      sp<int> myp4 = myptr1;
   }


   {

      std::cout << "Test with more complex objects\n";
      sp<tester> spt = new tester(1, "Keira Knightley");

      tester* p = spt.get();
      std::cout << "Name: " << p->get_name() << ", id: " << p->get_id() << '\n';

      // copying
      sp<tester> spt2 = spt;
      sp<tester> spt3(spt);

      sp<tester> spt4(new tester(2, "Cate Blanchett"));

      // re-assign
      spt = new tester(3, "Natalie Portman");

   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: How about better class name ?

Answer (score 3):

(1) Style nit: Prefer `#pragma once` to fragile `#ifndef`-based include guards. `#pragma once` isn't yet part of the standard; but any compiler that supports C++11 will definitely have supported `#pragma once` for years already.

(2) Obviously, remove the `std::cout` usage from your constructors when using this class for real. :)

(3) This is a MAJOR issue, and a common one, which is why I want to make a big deal of it:

```
T& operator*() { return *ptr_; }
const T& operator*() const { return *ptr_; }
```

No no *no* **no** ***no.*** You should provide only one `operator*`, and it should look like this:

```
T& operator*() const { return *ptr_; }
```

The act of dereferencing a (smart) pointer does not modify the *pointer object*, and therefore should be a `const` method of that *pointer object*. Also, the result of dereferencing a (smart) pointer to `T` had darn well better be a reference to `T`! Adding `const` to the return type is just plain wrong.

This is the same confusion that people often have between `int * const` and `int const *`, or between `std::vector<int>::iterator const` and `std::vector<int>::const_iterator`. In your case the confusion is between `sp<int> const` and `sp<int const>`.

(4) As above, you should have only one `operator->` and one `get()`, and both should be const methods:

```
T* operator->() const { return ptr_; }
T* get() const { return ptr_; }
```

(5) Your constructor should almost certainly be `explicit`:

```
explicit sp(T* ptr) : ptr_(ptr), ref_cnt_(new unsigned(1))
```

The exception-safety guarantees here look good to me. I would argue that `size_t` would be more appropriate than `unsigned` (you're probably paying for a 16-byte allocation anyway, so why not use that space?), but that's a nitpick.

If you really care about memory allocations, and want to keep learning about how the standard `shared_ptr` does things, you should try to implement the equivalent of `std::make_shared` for your smart pointer type, so that the memory allocations can be wrapped up together into a single call to `new`. I'd imagine that the tricky parts of `make_shared` have to do with alignment requirements.

(6) Your `ref_cnt_` doesn't point to a `std::atomic<unsigned>`, so `addref()` is not atomic; copying the same `sp` from two threads at once may result in undefined behavior.

(7) In C++11, it would be advisable to implement a **move constructor** and a **move assignment operator** in order to avoid a pointless `addref()` and `removeref()` when moving an rvalue. However, there's no problem with correctness in C++11; because you implement a user-defined copy constructor, the compiler will correctly suppress the generation of default move constructor and assignment functions (which would do the Wrong Thing if they *were* generated, so it's a good thing they're not).

(8) Your copy assignment operator performs unnecessary operations in the case that `x` is being assigned from a copy of `x`; for example:

```
sp<int> x(new int);
sp<int> y = x;  // adds a ref, correctly
x = y;  // removes a ref, then adds a ref; could be implemented as a no-op instead
```

(9) You don't use `remove_ref` except inside `try_delete`. Personally, I would inline the one call to `remove_ref`, and then rename `try_delete` to `remove_ref`. I would also rename `addref` to `add_ref` for consistency, and remove its unused return value.

(Future) To continue building your smart pointer into something like the standard's `std::shared_ptr`, consider the following use-cases:

```
sp<int> s(nullptr);  // or (int *)NULL
s = nullptr;
s.reset();  // same as =nullptr
```

Consider inheritance, upcasting and downcasting. This will require fleshing out your `ref_cnt_` pointer from `unsigned*` to `struct ref_cnt*`, and careful consideration of what metadata you need to keep in there.

```
class Mother { int m; };
class Father { int f; };
class Child : public Mother, public Father { int c; };

sp<Child> ch(new Child);
sp<Father> fa = ch;  // casting derived to base should work
ch.reset();
fa.reset();  // this should call ~Child on the correct pointer
```

Consider providing "weak references", which the standard library provides as `std::weak_ptr`. Weak references (`weak_ptr`) and strong references (`shared_ptr`) work tightly together, using the same infrastructure.

Consider providing the ability to pass in a custom deleter:

```
sp<char> buf(malloc(1024), (void(char*))free);
buf.reset();  // this should call free on the correct pointer
```